# Wordpress menu breaking only the last 2 items in IE8

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, menu

I have a site that for some reason is breaking in IE8 (fine in all other browsers) the last 2 menu items in the main navigation which in turn is messing up the whole page.

I cannot seems to find the source of the problem or anything on the web. The menu itself validates so it seems like it has something to do with jquery? I just can't find the problem.

Would appreciate any help!

Website:

http://www.finity.com.au

Answer (score 0):

Some validation errors in the menu: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   finity.com.au  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.finity.com.au/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. And Firebug shows a 403 and a 404 error, too.